# Node JS Security Group Creation AWS

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services

I have a JSON file that I'm calling into a file:

```
{
"SecurityGroups": [
    {
        "IpPermissionsEgress": [],
        "Description": "My security group",
        "IpPermissions": [
            {
                "PrefixListIds": [],
                "FromPort": 22,
                "IpRanges": [
                    {
                        "CidrIp": "203.0.113.0/24"
                    }
                ],
                "ToPort": 22,
                "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                "UserIdGroupPairs": []
            }
        ],
        "GroupName": "MySecurityGroup",
        "VPCId": "123456789012",
        "GroupId": "sg-903004f8",
    }
    ]
}
```

My JSON file looks like this:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/testuser/Documents/testsecuritygroups.json: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 696
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:588:27)
```

The error group name and description is clearly there. Not sure why I'm getting these errors. This is what my code looks like:

```
'use strict';

process.env.AWS_PROFILE

var PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
var properties = PropertiesReader('/Users/testuser/.aws/credentials');

AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId : properties.get('aws_access_key_id'),
        secretAccessKey : properties.get('aws_secret_access_key'),
        region : 'us-east-1'
})

var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'});

// Load credentials and set region from JSON file
// Load in security group parameters
let securityParams = require('./securityParams.json');
let securityParamsJSON = JSON.stringify(securityParams);

module.exports = {
    //Exports creation of Security Groups
    createSecurityGroup: (req, res) => {
        ec2.createSecurityGroup(securityParams[0].SecurityGroups[0], function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return (console.log("Error", err));
            }
            // Pass the Json as a parameter in this function
            ec2.authorizeSecurityGroupIngress(securityParams.IpPermissions, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    res.serverError(err, err.stack);
                } else {
                    res.ok(data);
                    console.log('Ingress Security Rules Created');
                }
            })
            // Pass the Json as a parameter in this function
            ec2.authorizeSecurityGroupEgress(securityParams.IpPermissionsEgress[0], function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    res.serverError(err, err.stack);
                } else {
                    res.ok(data);
                    console.log('Egress Security Rules Created');
                }
            })
        })
    }
  }
module.exports.createSecurityGroup();
```

I'm just trying to create security groups in AWS through this script.

Comment: The parameters you're passing to `createSecurityGroup` don't seem to match the ones [indicated in the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html) -- You might try `securityParams[0].UserIdGroupPairs[0]`

Comment: That seemed to help! `RequestExpired: Request has expired.` Thats the new error I'm getting.

Comment: Where are you getting that error from? Which `ec2` command?

Comment: I'm getting that after the script is run

Comment: I'm pretty sure Amazon throws that error when the time of my local machine and the remote server are off by more than 15 mins. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=38360